# Generate SSH Putty private pair using C# RSACryptoServiceProvider class

Tags: c#, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I need to create Putty supported SSH RSA keys pragmatically using C# language. I have explored we can create public/private keys using C# inbuilt class *RSACryptoServiceProvider*. The putty keys format is as follows

Private Key:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-key
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAEAAEAAQAAAQEA0dB2SzZoaMLgYePcbtU6YmCEq50cWpcd
hRTxTTs3wXgKhAP8GA/KSrCZBI+tbqwsVOoGnlGVg0ylftSIOQE/eVJIAoIayT6l
P6IAGNhgcVQ5+8QsShopW1lx37m2Ni5HGzrU9DE4EXa7AxIYehwXegWP+O/Pc7bw
+r6yU9m0ncAaphHmOwuNoFx/SZslXPkXVEiw40zL54OLOELDIzlZ7KjEykcPqF3o
kiMfoyvUaxh1HW/KBGu7mbpk6SF+iqG3EFqlIbR5gcQQAAP5cXAgHoXFvTpMh+am
5ZVmH98ErjAEwNQq0vCyKCvQLCl8kY4+2CfO5b8LtxnnX7H7lTqrTQ==
Private-Lines: 14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Private-MAC: 4e102b5eeee013706ab755fdaca0f8c4fe49662b
```

Public Key

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: imported-key
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAEAAEAAQAAAQEA0dB2SzZoaMLgYePcbtU6YmCEq50cWpcd
hRTxTTs3wXgKhAP8GA/KSrCZBI+tbqwsVOoGnlGVg0ylftSIOQE/eVJIAoIayT6l
P6IAGNhgcVQ5+8QsShopW1lx37m2Ni5HGzrU9DE4EXa7AxIYehwXegWP+O/Pc7bw
+r6yU9m0ncAaphHmOwuNoFx/SZslXPkXVEiw40zL54OLOELDIzlZ7KjEykcPqF3o
kiMfoyvUaxh1HW/KBGu7mbpk6SF+iqG3EFqlIbR5gcQQAAP5cXAgHoXFvTpMh+am
5ZVmH98ErjAEwNQq0vCyKCvQLCl8kY4+2CfO5b8LtxnnX7H7lTqrTQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I have explored the following article regarding this, but the keys generated through this are not working.
https://antonymale.co.uk/generating-putty-key-files.html

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: I do not have an answer. But I've seen similar question here recently about PPK key generated by PHP code. It turned out that recent versions of PuTTY (and PuTTYgen) are more strict and won't load certain keys, which previous versions did. And it seems to be the case here too. If I use the code from your link to generate a key, it won't load into latest PuTTYgen 0.73. But it loads to PuTTYgen 0.60 (I've picked that version randomly). If you save the loaded key back, it will load to PuTTYgen 0.73 without a problem. So try to compare how does the re-saved file differ from the generated one.

Comment: I too tried this scenario, but I didn't find any mechanism to  compare these keys.